# UiPath queue transaction status flow - Require better understanding

Tags: uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I am playing/learning UiPath queue and transaction behavior and so far I have understood few things as per the documentation and tutorials. However, what I am missing in the document and in the forum is how that transaction status flow work and when/where/how can we update the transaction status?

So far what I have achieved is:-

- When we add new item to the queue the status that get assigned in orchestrator is New
- After that we use GetItemTransaction activity to get the transaction item, and then we can change the status to either success or failed using Set Transaction Status activity.
- If we don't use the Set Transaction Status activity and just leave GetItemTransaction activity blank the status that get assigned in Orchestrator is Progress

My question is, is that all we can do with the status or how can we change the status to whatever we like using Studio and Orchestrator both at any given time to any given status from any given status.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It's just Failed and Success (and Progress). There is no way currently to solve your issue. It's just not designed for those specific usage. But maybe you just add a property called `status` and read this one instead? But may I ask which Status beyond these both are useful to have?

Comment: Thanks for providing the input, I asked that question for better understanding of the current behaviour and you just answered that by saying "I don't think that's possible". I also agree with that behaviour and just wondering what I am understanding is correct. Hoever adding custom status attribute to the transaction item is not a bad idea but then we will loose the orchestraotr default bhaviour.

Comment: But you already described it very well my friend. Just the part of setting the progress was missing. And you asked for `My question is, is that all we can do with the status`. You didn't say that you want a whole description =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we add new item to the queue the status that get assigned in
>   orchestrator is New

This is correct, except if the queue item is added using the Add Transaction Item activity. In such cases, the status of the newly added queue item (called *transaction* at this point) is **In Progress**.

> After that we use GetItemTransaction activity to get the transaction
>   item, and then we can change the status to either success or failed
>   using Set Transaction Status activity.

Note that the status is automatically changed to **In Progress** if you use the Get Transaction Item activity, even if you don't use any other activity (like Set Transaction Status) after that.

> If we don't use the Set Transaction Status activity and just leave
>   GetItemTransaction activity blank the status that get assigned in
>   Orchestrator is Progress

If the status is not changed, it stays **In Progress** for a fixed amount of time (usually 24h), but then it becomes **Abandoned**.

> My question is, is that all we can do with the status or how can we
>   change the status to whatever we like using Studio and Orchestrator
>   both at any given time to any given status from any given status.

There isn't a single activity that allows you to change the status to any of the available statuses, so it's recommended to use the appropriated activity to get to the status that you want (for example, if you want **Success** or **Failed**, use Set Transaction Status). For more statuses, please check https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/queue-item-statuses

Having said that, it is possible to assign a custom progress status to a queue item using the Set Transaction Progress activity: https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/managing-queues-in-studio#section-adding-a-custom-progress. With this, it's possible to add progress statuses that are more meaningful to a particular process that is being automated.

Comment: For this is just a description of Transaction settings. I thought the question was about how to solve the issue. Maybe the question should be reworked.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly we can not add the custom statuses but we can add the custom strings to inprogress items in order to track the transaction but still, it will not be possible to put the filter on custom strings.
Activity to add the custom string is - "**Set Transaction Progress**"